# Apache2: mod_ratelimit only allowing half the speed

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, .htaccess, apache2

I'm trying to limit the file download speed in a directory

I've got the following .htaccess

```
<IfModule ratelimit_module>
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 4096
</IfModule>
```

But this only allows 2MB/s, on my browser and curl.

Changing rate-limit to 8000 allows 4MB/s

What could be causing this missing factor of 2?

Comment: The site's running through cloudflare for a proxy, perhaps that's causing some kind of doubling. But I'd expect it to just be client -> cloudflare -> server